# taking symbol in sum [sympy]

Tags: python, sympy

For example, I'd like to solve

[image]
<sub>(source: [texify.com](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Cdisplayst%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5EN%5C%20n%5E2%5C%20%3D%5C%2055.gif))</sub>

Here's what I tried:

```
from sympy import var, solve
x = var('x')
f = lambda N: sum( n**2 for n in range(1,N+1) )
f(x)

# output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Add.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's built-in `range()` function isn't aware of symbolic evaluation.  Try using SymPy's `sum()` function instead:

```
>>> from sympy import sum, var, solve
>>> x = var('x')
>>> f = lambda N: sum(n**2, (n, 1, N))
>>> n = var("n")
>>> f(x)
x/6 + x**2/2 + x**3/3
```

Note that the lambda expression might be unnecessary, depending on you actually want to achieve:

```
>>> N = var("N")
>>> solve(sum(n**2, (n, 1, N)) - 55, N)
[-13/4 - I*359**(1/2)/4, 5, -13/4 + I*359**(1/2)/4]
```

You'll still have to ignore the complex results.

Comment: @weis26: Sorry, my answer was slightly wrong. `Sum()` seems to be for numerical evaluation `sympy.sum()` is for symbolic evaluation.

Comment: Just an afterthought. Is there a way to use the summation function `f(N) = Σ n²` for both numerical evaluation [ as in f(3) ] and solving a equation [ as in f(N) = 55 ]? Do I have to define 2 functions one using `sum` and the other using `sympy.sum`?

Comment: The two functions I was talking about in my previous comment are `sympy.Sum()` and `sympy.sum()`.  Don't confuse them with the built-in function `sum()`.  To numerically evaluate a symbolic sum, use the `subs()` method of SymPy expressions, e.g. `sum(n**2, (n, 1, N)).subs(N, 5)`.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this, `sum` has been renamed to `summation` in SymPy to avoid conflicting with the Python builtin.

Answer (score 3):

Try the summation function

```
In [1]: n = Symbol('n', real=True)

In [2]: N = Symbol('N', real=True)

In [3]: summation(n**2, (n, 1, N)) # sum n**2 taking n from 1 to N
Out[3]: 
 3    2    
N    N    N
── + ── + ─
3    2    6

In [4]: solve(summation(n**2, (n, 1, N)) - 55, N)
Out[4]: [5]
```

Comment: You need to import `Symbol` and `summation` from `sympy` first.
Or just use `import sympy; sympy.Symbol; sympy.summation`